# WordPress: Move blog to page

Tags: wordpress

i need to move my WordPress Blog Entries to a page.

I've installed WordPress to subfolder (`http://example.com/canada/`) and currently i access my Blog entries with following URL: `http://example.com/canada/hello-world/`

But i would like to call my Blog entries like this: `http://example.com/canada/blog/hello-world`.

I know i can choose a static page for my entries under `Options -> Reading`. But if i set the option for entry page to Blog nothing happends.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem my own... I've defined a new **custom post type** named blog. Works as i aspected :)

### Working Solution:

```
function post_type_blog() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Entries', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Entry', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add', 'entry'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add new Entry'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit'),
        'new_item' => __('New'),
        'view_item' => __('Visit'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Entries'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'), 
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
        );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array("slug" => "blog"), // Permalinks format
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','comments')
    ); 

    register_post_type('blog',$args);
}
add_action('init', 'post_type_blog');
```

### Important note:

Don't forget to refresh your permalinks. Otherwise you'll get an 404.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, in `Settings > Permalinks` set the following Custom Structure for your permalinks:

```
/blog/%postname%/
```

Comment: Sure... but in this case all my custom post types and pages would also have `/blog' in the url.